# Authentication in .htaccess file for sub directories

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following structure:

```
_auth/
   ->.htpasswd
website1/
website2/
website3/
.htaccess
```

I want to add a AuthType Basic to my .htaccess in root directory, so that webiste1/ and website2/ require authentification and website3/ should be still accessible without. All three websites have there own domain.

I tried:

```
<directory "/website1">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile "_auth/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</directory>

<directory "/website2">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile "_auth/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
</directory>
```

But its not working

Comment: "its not working" - What happened exactly? If you had put the above into a `.htaccess` file then it _should_ have broken your server and you _should_ have seen a 500 Internal Server Error response? Is that what happened? Otherwise, there are other issues to resolve.

Comment: All pages are not working anymore. I get a error message from my Hoster. In Log file I get the following: "[Directory not allowed here". Do you know if there is an alternative way to set the protection of several directories via .htaccess in a root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<Directory>` containers in `.htaccess` files. (The `.htaccess` file itself is essentially a *directory* container and *directory* containers cannot be nested.)

Assuming you're on Apache 2.4 and `/website1` and `/website2` appear as part of the requested URL-path, then you can use an Apache Expression.

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/(website1|website2)/#">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile "_auth/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

Note that the *file-path* `_auth/.htpasswd` is seen as relative to the defined *ServerRoot*. You should otherwise specify an absolute filesystem path, such as:

```
AuthUserFile "/abs/path/to/_auth/.htpasswd"
```